# Installing Canon LBP2900b printer in 12.10

Tags: drivers, software-installation, 12.10, printing, canon

I installed  Canon LBP2900B 's driver from canon's support page in Ubuntu 12.10. In printers section it is showing my printer as LBP2900 (not as LBP2900B). I can open its properties, can send a command for printing. What's wrong, however, is that in the printing process, it is shown as processing. Suffice it to say that my printer is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this page of the Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190) and follow the instructions for 12.04.

Comment: I have tried everything that was given on this page(
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190?action=show&redirect=CanonCaptPrinterDriver), ad the last command I used for monitoring the printer, it gives an error.

raman@raman-Satellite-A660:~$ captstatusui -P 2900

*** captstatusui Socket Error ***

Comment: :(  I followed every step given on this site again and again. But the problem remained same. SADLY I have to shift to Windows again. I dont wana go back to that os.

Now in printer state, it shows this error
( Printer State:Idle - ccp send_data error, exit)

Comment: Got little more things. Now status monitor appears and displaying following messege

Connection Error

Check the followings:
-Is the printer turned on?
-Is the cable correctly connected?

Comment: community dont like helping with teamwiewer . but i will help you with it. after i will write everything what i did

Comment: install teamwiewer and send me pass and id eneskuray@windowslive.com

Comment: ooohhh!!! yes finally I heard my printer,s sweet voice

Comment: @ToorRamanpreet you'r welcome

Answer (score -1):

I've searched for you this driver and I found it in this page:
http://www.canon.co.uk/Support/Consumer_Products/products/printers/Laser/i-SENSYS_LBP2900B.aspx?DLtcmuri=tcm:14-846492&page=1&type=download

However, I don't know where do you live, so if you click here
http://www.canon.co.uk/Support/Consumer_Products/products/printers/Laser/i-SENSYS_LBP2900B.aspx?type=download&page=1
you can choose your own language for this driver!
Unfortunately I have not tried to search the guide for install the printer. If you have any problems write here, even if I'm a beginner of Ubuntu I'm trying to help all of you!

Comment: if you will click on the second link, you have to click on "Software (drivers and applications)" situated near "Please select a download type"

Comment: thanx but the problem is same..
In printing queue window it shows processing..

Comment: I have tried everything that was given on this page(https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190?action=show&redirect=CanonCaptPrinterDriver ), ad the last command I used for monitoring the printer, it gives an error. raman@raman-Satellite-A660:~$ captstatusui -P 2900 *** captstatusui Socket Error ***

Comment: I followed the procedure given by canon with this driver package too

Comment: ooohhh!!! yes finally I heard my printer,s sweet voice