# Install Canon i-SENSYS LBP7200Cdn network printer on Ubuntu 12.10 64bit

Tags: 12.10, drivers, printing, canon

I want to use [Canon i-SENSYS LBP7200Cdn](http://software.canon-europe.com/products/0010709.asp) network printer with Ubuntu 12.10. I have read official documentation, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221052/installing-canon-lbp2900b-printer-in-12-10) and [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190?action=show&redirect=CanonCaptPrinterDriver). I have not achieved any solution yet. I tried CAPT software versions [2.20](http://software.canon-europe.com/software/0040567.asp?model=) and [2.40](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/4/0900007724/12/Linux_CAPT_PrinterDriver_V240_uk_EN.tar.gz). All the manuals are different and always involve CUPS and CCPD services, but nothing helped me.

Comment: Could you please say what you have done? Which steps?

Comment: @BuZZ-dEE I have followed the steps described in both posts. None of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Unzip the contents of the driver download, select the 32-bit or 64-bit folder, debian, and extract the .deb files to a directory. To install, open in console and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i ./*.deb
```

Comment: I did it, obviously, it doesn't work. Moreover, the deb's have unsatisfied dependencies that Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't have.

Comment: That's strange, it says dependency error on libraries that are installed. Running `sudo dpkg -i --force-depends ./*.deb` installs it anyway, see if that works.

Comment: The maintainer listed in the .deb is sup-debian@list.canon.co.jp, you should probably report the bug to them.

Comment: If I use force option, it doesn't work, obviously, because the binaries failed to load library dependencies. Some packages had changed the names.

Comment: Try to install those manually, and if they're only renamed libraries (incorrect dependencies in .deb file), --force-depends should make it install anyway.

Comment: I have tested it and I think it was all correct, but I cannot connect to the printer anyway. Anyway I think Cannon should provide updated software for Linux users and current major distros, like Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you get any response from that maintainers' email?

Comment: no response received from maintainer...

Comment: Did you try calling support?

Comment: calling support, haha. no, they only support old versions of Ubuntu officially...

Comment: MX882 works fine with 12.10 64bit, but maybe your driver was compiled long ago... Have you tried compiling the driver? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo

Comment: it is an option, but I hope it is possible to use the printer with binary drivers, avoiding any manual compilation. maybe I try...