# My KUBUNTU 18.04 with KDE Plasma 5.12.7 does not print on Cannon LBP2900B

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, printing, kde, canon

Even after trying everything from the answers of following threads:

1. ) [Installing Canon LBP2900b printer in 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221052/installing-canon-lbp2900b-printer-in-12-10)

2.) [How do I install Canon LBP2900B printer in UBUNTU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/687059/how-do-i-install-canon-lbp2900b-printer-in-ubuntu)

3.) [How to make Canon LBP2900B work on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/956674/how-to-make-canon-lbp2900b-work-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

4.) [Installing Canon LBP2900b printer in 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221052/installing-canon-lbp2900b-printer-in-12-10)

5.) [How To Install Canon LBP2900B printer in 14.04 LTS ? I tried the method for LBP2900 but it didnt work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487627/how-to-install-canon-lbp2900b-printer-in-14-04-lts-i-tried-the-method-for-lbp2)

I am still not able to print anything from my computer using UBUNTU 18.04.

But If  boot the same computer with Windows 7 OS (It is a Dual Boot Computer with KUBUNTU and Windows 7), the same setup works fine and prints just fine.

Please help me solve this issue.